# In-App Data For Chrome Apps

Tags: javascript, file, dynamic, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome App to allow users to create virtual documents that are stored within the app itself, meaning I don't want the users to have direct access to the files.

The reason why this is is because when the app first starts, it's a screen showing previews/thumbnails of all the created files. If I gave users control over where the files were stored, this could be interferred with by having multiple files in various locations.

What I'd like to do is store everything inside of the app. If possible, I'd like to use JavaScript to create, modify, and edit files within the packaged app, not through the user-accessible file system. Is there any way to dynamically add files and folders to a packaged app using JavaScript?

If not, what are my options for a controlled system in which users cannot move their files to a different directory to keep my thumbnails/previews intact?

Answer (score 1):

You only have [read-only access](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry) to your package directory.

For an isolated virtual filesystem specific to your app, you should use the HTML5 [Filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). *Yes, it has a big warning regarding its status, but it's the basis of Chrome's own APIs so it is not going anywhere in Chrome.*

You should carefully consider though if it's really the best experience for your users. The good part though, if you ever wish to allow to use a location on the real filesystem, you don't need to change much - the [`chrome.fileSystem` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) simply provides another `DirectoryEntry`, but the rest of working with it is pretty much the same.